# Colcon build and source install/setup.bash not finding packages

Tags: ros, roslaunch, colcon, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

after using colcon build to compile Autoware 1.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 with ros kinetic , some times when running the script

```
 source autoware_dir/install/setup.bash
```

I receive an error that the packages are not found, and of therefore  roslaunch or rosrun fails to find any nodes in the packages.
The error is:

```
 user@locahost:~/autoware.ai$ source install/setup.bash
 not found: "/home/user/autoware.ai/install/adi_driver
 autoware_bag_tools
 autoware_build_flags
 autoware_can_msgs
 ..."
```

It turns out the problem is the way bash script tokenizes string variables (see below). My question is regarding the likely cause of the problem.

###Question
Is it a problem with my environment? I may have messed up some environment variable or installed the wrong version of something. I would think if it is a problem with the colcon scripts themselves many other people would have similar problems.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what might be wrong?

I List the out put of various version info below.

EDIT: bash IFS is being overwritten by rosrun autocomplete. See below.

###Cause of Problem
The error occurs because the script file install/local_setup.bash generates a list of package names which is a string with package names separated by (I think) line breaks.
When the script then tries to add a prefix (path) to each package name, it treats the list of names as one single string.and of course can't find the file named after all packages. The relevant part of the script (`install/local_setup.bash`, from line 93) is

```
# get all packages in topological order                                                            
_colcon_ordered_packages="$($_colcon_python_executable "$_colcon_prefix_bash_COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX_local_setup_util.py")"                                                                           
unset _colcon_python_executable                                                                    
                                                                                               
# source package specific scripts in topological order                                             
for _colcon_package_name in $_colcon_ordered_packages; do                                          
      # setting COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX avoids relying on the build time prefix of the sourced script    
     COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX="${_colcon_prefix_bash_COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX}/${_colcon_package_name}"     
     _colcon_prefix_bash_source_script "$COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX/share/${_colcon_package_name}/package.bash"                                                                                              
done
```

The ordered package string generated by the python script is iterated over in the for loop. In this case the string `_colcon_ordered_packages` is not tokenised and only one giant string is processed within the loop.

###Work Around
By using a `while read -r _colcon_package_name; do` .... `done <<< "$_colcon_ordered_packages` to iterate the string can be successfully tokenised and then sourced using the appropriate package.bash script

```
# source package specific scripts in topological order                                             
while read -r _colcon_package_name; do                                                                                                 
      # setting COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX avoids relying on the build time prefix of the sourced script    
      COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX="${_colcon_prefix_bash_COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX}/${_colcon_package_name}"     
      _colcon_prefix_bash_source_script "$COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX/share/${_colcon_package_name}/package.bash"                                                                                              
done <<< "$_colcon_ordered_packages"
```

Edit: fixed quotation marks

Edit: add

###Persistent Work Around

Using `_colcon_pthon_executable` variable in above script,  to find out what version of python colcon is using (in my case python3), and depending on what shell you are using (bash) edit the file :

```
 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_bash/shell/template/prefix.bash.em
```

This file is used by the colcon python module to generate the relevant part of `install/local_setup.bash`.
Making the same change to the string tokenizer as above results in a workaround that will be persistent between builds.

Note: line numbers are slightly different in the template file.

###Environment

`$_colcon_python_executable`  evaluates to python3 (version 3.5.2)

GNU Bash version 4.3.48(1)

`colcon version-check`

```
colcon-argcomplete 0.3.2: newer version available (0.3.3)
colcon-bash 0.3.2: up-to-date
colcon-cmake 0.2.8: newer version available (0.2.13)
colcon-core 0.3.19: newer version available (0.3.23) 
colcon-defaults 0.2.1: newer version available (0.2.2)
colcon-devtools 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-library-path 0.2.1: up-to-date
colcon-metadata 0.2.1: newer version available (0.2.2)
colcon-notification 0.2.7: newer version available (0.2.9)
colcon-output 0.2.3: newer version available (0.2.4)
colcon-package-information 0.2.2: newer version available (0.2.3)
colcon-package-selection 0.2.4: up-to-date
colcon-parallel-executor 0.2.3: newer version available (0.2.4)
colcon-pkg-config 0.1.0: up-to-date
colcon-powershell 0.3.4: up-to-date
colcon-python-setup-py 0.2.1: newer version available (0.2.2)
colcon-recursive-crawl 0.2.0: up-to-date
colcon-ros 0.3.8: newer version available (0.3.11)
colcon-test-result 0.3.1: newer version available (0.3.5)
colcon-zsh 0.3.2: up-to-date
```

#### Edit with Update - Cause of problem

Thanks to Dirk Thomas's comment I think the problem is using rosrun autocompletion is causing the bash shell IFS to be overwritten. If I start a new terminal:

```
 user@locahost:~$ echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
 0000000  sp  ht  nl
         040 011 012
              \t  \n
 0000003
 user@localhost:~$ rosrun m
 map_msgs            message_generation  move_base_msgs
 ...
 user@localhost:~$ echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
 0000000
 user@localhost:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330128/colcon-build-and-source-install/setup.bash-not-finding-packages/) by [simon-t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/41791/simon-t4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-08-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [simon-t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/41791/simon-t4/) on 2019-08-08**:
Added a persistent (between builds) work around

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-08-08**:
My guess would be that you override the `IFS` in your bash configuration. Can you double check it and post the value you are using?

**Comment by [simon-t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/41791/simon-t4/) on 2019-08-08**:
Thanks, you are right.
Open new terminal:

```
  echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
  0000000  sp  ht  nl
                040 011 012
                  \t  \n
  0000003
```

Run `source install/setup.bash`, gives the original error, then

```
  echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
  0000000
```

Which I guess means that an overwrite occurs and there are no IFS set.

The overwrite  also seems to occurs when using the workaround, but the sourcing works. Somewhere in the setup.bash script IFS is being overwritten, I'll try to pinpoint where.

**Comment by [simon-t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/41791/simon-t4/) on 2019-08-08**:
The auto-complete function on rosrun seems to overwriting the IFS value.
See original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To officially answer:

###Cause of problem

Thanks to Dirk Thomas's comment I think the problem is using rosrun autocompletion is causing the bash shell IFS to be overwritten. If I start a new terminal:

```
 user@locahost:~$ echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
  0000000  sp  ht  nl
           040 011 012
                         \t  \n
   0000003
   user@localhost:~$ rosrun m
   map_msgs            message_generation  move_base_msgs
  ...
  user@localhost:~$ echo -n "$IFS" | od -abc
  0000000
  user@localhost:~$
```

###Persistent Work Around
Using _colcon_pthon_executable variable in local_setup.bash script to find out what version of python colcon is using (in my case python3), and depending on what shell you are using (bash) edit the file :

```
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_bash/shell/template/prefix.bash.em
```

This file is used by the colcon python module to generate the relevant part of install/local_setup.bash. When IFS is overwritten the loop to construct package names fails because string is not tokensied properly.

By using a while read -r _colcon_package_name; do .... done <<< "$_colcon_ordered_packages to iterate the string can be successfully tokenised and then sourced using the appropriate package.bash script

```
 # source package specific scripts in topological order                                             
 while read -r _colcon_package_name; do                                                                                                 
       # setting COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX avoids relying on the build time prefix of the sourced script    
       COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX="${_colcon_prefix_bash_COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX}/${_colcon_package_name}"     
       _colcon_prefix_bash_source_script "$COLCON_CURRENT_PREFIX/share/${_colcon_package_name}/package.bash"                                                                                              
 done <<< "$_colcon_ordered_packages"
```

---

Originally posted by [simon-t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/41791/simon-t4/) with karma: 41 on 2019-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-08-28**:
I tried to create a patch to restore the IFS in `rosrun` after it is modifying it: https://github.com/ros/ros/pull/227 It would be great if you could give it a try and report back if it addresses the problem for you.

**Comment by [simon-t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/41791/simon-t4/) on 2019-08-30**:
Thanks for your work. Unfortunately (if I have applied the patch correctly) the problem still persists with the new version of rosrun.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-04**:
Thanks for giving it a try. I have since then updated the PR and double checked that it works for me. It would be great if you could give it another try and report back again.

**Comment by [simon-t4](https://answers.ros.org/users/41791/simon-t4/) on 2019-09-17**:
Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately there is still the same behavior. I am simply editing /opt/ros/bin/rosrun script to reflect the changes you suggest. So I might not be testing correctly.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-09-17**:
You also need to patch the `rosbash` file since that is doing the completion.